# "..." at the end of a Java String = not enough room in memory?

Tags: java, string, parsing, max, htmlunit

I've written a parsing program that appraises lists of information and appends the price at the end of the entry.  I'm using HTMLUnit to get a string of the page I want to view using asText().  My code snippet reads as follows:

```
HtmlPage page = wc.getPage(name.substring(0, name.length() - 1));
wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(100);
String test = page.asText();
```

In one of my cases, the string has an index count of 111,471 (according to the Eclipse debugger) and it ends in "...", which I'm assuming means this particular variable has no more space in the memory to store additional information.  The string as is doesn't contain the entire webpage and the bit I need to extract is at the very bottom of the page.  Is there a way I can parse strings of this size?

Comment: The debugger doesn't want to display the 100K chars of the strings, so it truncates it. But the string actually contains everything. Just print it, and you'll see.

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior in the Eclipse debugger? It may be the debugger that's not showing you the whole string. Try writing it to a file and look there.

Comment: Did you _try_ to parse and failed? The `...` in the debugger sounds like it's just truncating the view, since it's hard to show a 111,471-char string in a tooltip hover. If you set a watch point to get the last 50 or so chars (`s.substring(s.length() - 50)`), does it show you what you'd expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that *the string as is doesn't contain the entire webpage*? Printing strings to the console can lead to ellipsis (or truncating, shown as *...*) if the string is very long. That doesn't mean however, that it's cut off at the point of ellipsis.

Have you tried treating the string, and did you get any errors? Or do you just *assume* that it is incomplete?